Vulnerability of key exchange arising from interoperability of implementations
I remember that I read a paper a long time ago that makes a claim of the following kind:
Although TLS (or perhaps another protocol) is secure in theory, different implementations of it could interpret the spec in slightly different ways. If everyone uses the same implementation, everyone is safe. However when different implementations interoperate, the slight differences could lead to exploitable vulnerabilities.
I cannot find this paper. Are there papers making similar claims? I remember the paper is not about a downgrade attack, nor any attack listed on Wikipedia.

I found the paper I was mentioning. On the (in)security of ElGamal in OpenPGP. https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/923.pdf
